# Jsoup login in to ModelMayhem

Tags: authentication, jsoup, session-cookies

I'm trying to write a program to log in to model mayhem using Jsoup so that I can process certain emails without having to actually log in.  However, I'm having a really hard time figuring out exactly what the connection needs to work.  Here's my code so far

```
Connection connection = Jsoup
        .connect("https://secure.modelmayhem.com/login/action");
connection.timeout(40000);
connection.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) "
        + "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
        + "Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36");
Connection.Response res = connection
        .data("email", username)
        .data("password", password).data("check", "Login")
        .data("ReturnUri", "").method(Method.POST).execute();
Map<String, String> cookies = res.cookies();
System.out.println(cookies); // validates that the PHPSESSID is coming back

Connection connection2 = Jsoup
        .connect("http://www.modelmayhem.com/mystuff");
connection2.timeout(40000);
connection2.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) "
        + "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
        + "Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36");
connection2.cookies(cookies);

Document document = connection2.execute().parse();
System.out.println(document);
```

But no matter what I try, I always get sent back to the login page.
Can you figure out what I need to do differently?

Thanks,

Steph

Answer (score 0):

You can try to collect the cookies starting from url: https://secure.modelmayhem.com/login
And I used to collect all the returned cookies into one map.

```
cookies.putAll(response1.cookies());
connection2.cookies(cookies);
...
cookies.putAll(response2.cookies());
connection3.cookies(cookies);
```